# Does playing Hard mode remove all energy tanks?

Tags: cave-story

When playing hard mode I noticed that some energy tanks are missing when playing. Is this all of the tanks and will I be stuck on three health all the way though the game or is it only some of the tanks that are removed? Are there any other power ups that are removed in hard mode?

Comment: Could you add a tag for which system you're playing on? Evidently the 3ds version's hard mode is not quite as brutal as the wii's.

Comment: @Fambida I'm playing the version I got from the humble bundle, I'm not sure if that's the Wii version or not.

Comment: Hard mode enforces the Three Heart Challenge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In hard mode all life capsules but one have been removed, all chests containing missiles have been removed, the chest containing super missiles can't be opened, and the sisters don't appear.

I'll edit again if I can find some better sources.